# Wordpress theme, best way to find code location

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I have a Wordpress theme & need to replace the logo upon scrolling down.

Should be simple enough but after hours of sifting through code and testing, no dice.

Could anyone tell me the best way to view the front end of a production website and follow the code through to the correct location in the files/code?

I am using FileZilla & Notepad ++, have followed file names and searched for elements.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe a stupid answer but did you try to inspect the elements most of the times you can see the path and file location.

Comment: "There's no such things as stupid questions just stupid people" Haha mine was pretty vague sorry. 

I did try this and couldn't find all of the elements locations in particular the one which changes the navigation background colour as you scroll down the page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your theme files are located in `/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/`

Go to the folder for your current, active theme - you can either search for the elements after inspecting them in your browser, or you can learn a little about [WordPress template hierachy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) so that you can expect where to find which block/snippet of code that you are trying to edit.

Comment: I am looking through them though I don't know what the elements are called. Have opened everything and doing searches etc.... Was hoping someone would have a more direct method or plugin for Chrome etc...

Comment: Judging by your comment above, you are looking for the CSS that changes the background color. Your theme's main stylesheet is located in that folder I referred to, inspect the element in your browser and find the relevant CSS selector and then do a "find" in the stylesheet for that selector and look for the values that you want to change.